# Permutations of a word with repetitions and conditions

Tags: permutations

```
How many permutations of "committee" exist where is must not end in an e?
```

I've been trying to figure out a possible angle of attack on this question.

I've tried to say instead, "how many possible ways are there that **do** end in an e?". However, this is causing me problems as there are letter repetitions.

Where should I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

Total number of ways "COMMITTEE" could be formed is $$\frac{9!}{2!2!2!}$$

Now fix "E" in the last position and compute the different number of ways to permute the rest. This is

$$\frac{8!}{2!2!}$$

Now the total number of ways "COMMITTEE" could be formed in such a way that it does not end with an "E" is

$$\frac{9!}{2!2!2!} - \frac{8!}{2!2!}$$

Comment: okay great, all of the previous answers are good but yours made the most sense to me. If i am interpreting you correctly, then to "fix" e to the end, are you essentially saying you are making an 8 letter word "committe" instead?

Comment: Yes, you are making a eight letter word committe which is different from a 9 letter word not to end in "e"

Answer (score 3):

There are $9$ slots to be filled. An e cannot be at the end, so we can pick the pair of locations occupied by the e's in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways. For each of these, the locations of the m's can be picked in $\binom{7}{2}$ ways. Now the locations of the t's can be chosen in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. The remaining $3$ slots can be filled in $3!$ ways.  This gives a total of $\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}3!$ words.

**Remark:** It is very useful to place the e's first. The order in which we consider the rest does not matter. For example, after the e's are placed, the c can be placed in $\binom{7}{1}$ ways. For each of these, the t's can be placed in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. and so on.

Comment: regarding you remark: essentially then, we are making an 8 letter word with "committe" instead?

Comment: I had a "typo" in the remark. We place the e's. That leaves a $7$-letter word to be made from committ.

Comment: @Andre, our answers seem to differ, Am I making an error

Comment: where am I missing is it because we have two e's

Comment: Compute, they do not differ. Mine is $\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}3!$, which is $35280$. I think your $\frac{9!}{8}-\frac{8!}{4}$ is the same.

Comment: @Andre, you are correct!! Thanks

Comment: Yes i have computed both of your answers, and they are both correct. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$committee=c^1*o^1*m^2*i^1*t^2+e^2$

For any word how many permutations give the same word? The letters $t$ can be switched (2 ways), the letters $m$ can be switched (2 ways) and the letters $e$ can also be switched (2 ways) therefore for any word there are $2\cdot2\cdot2=8$ permutations giving the same word.

Thus there are $\dfrac {8!}{8}=7!$ words.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem 3 of chapter 1 from Lászlo Lovász book Combinatorial Problems and Excercises. He uses the word caharacterization. Here I copy what  he says about the word characterization.

There are 16! permutations of the word CHARACTERIZATION however not all of these give new words; in fact,in any permutation, if we exchange the three $A$'s,the two $C$'s,the two $R$'s,the two $I$'s or the two $T$'s we get the same word. Thus for any permutation, there are $3!\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot=96$ permutations which give the same word, so the result is $\frac{16!}{96}$

In General, if there are $k_A$  $A$'s, $k_b$  $B$'s etc. then the result is

$\dfrac{k_A+k_b+\dots}{k_A!k_B!\dots}$